# C# not detecting and instantiating classes

Tags: c#, .net

I started writing a new C# app. I have created a couple of classes that i would like to declare and instantiate in a Form. The thing is, when i write it, the intellisense does not detect it. I will provide a screen shot, as I don't know how to better explain. [image: screenshot of C# not detecting classes]

Comment: this could be a cache problem, try deleting it https://hanskindberg.wordpress.com/2014/02/27/visual-studio-clear-cache/

Comment: Probably `Ctrl+.` to add a missing using statement.

Comment: Show the full definition of DataHelper, with its namespace.

Comment: Going by the code you posted of your `DataHelper` class: why does that one have a different namespace -- `BuildID` -- as the form above -- `BuildID_Company_Backend`? Don't manually alter namespaces; your file structure and namespaces should correspond with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataHelper` is defined under the `BuildID` namespace.

You have 2 options:

The **first** is to declare it like this:

`private BuildID.DataHelper _dataHelper //...;`

The **second** is to add a `using BuildID` at the top of the page, you can either write it manually or have your cursor on the `DataHelper` object which is unrecognized (at the moment), press

`Ctrl + .` and choose the option that the Visual Studio offers you, to add the using statement automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I Think to instantiate it you wanna do
"Private DataHelper data = new DataHelper();

Comment: Yes, that is what i am trying to do, but normally Visual Studio will make a suggestion when i write DataHelper, and it would make it in blue color, meaning that it recognizes the class. This however does not happen for me.

Comment: if intellisense doesn't catch it that's ok intellisense sometimes break with cache issues,  you can restart visual studio to bring back intellisense. other than that did you reference Data Helper correctly into your program?